# 500 Error when debug=false Django. Works fine when DEBUG=true

Tags: django

also have s3 buckets set up and that works fine when debug=true. Not sure whats going on. allowed hosts are good and i also did python manage.py collectstatic. anyone know th problem??

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
import os
import dj_database_url
from django.conf import settings
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY',)

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = bool( os.environ.get('DEBUG', False) )
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['quickthrift-andregrandon.herokuapp.com', '198.211.99.20', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
        'allauth.account',
        'allauth.socialaccount',
    'home',
    'products',



]

SITE_ID = 1
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'mio.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'allauth'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request', # required by allauth
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mio.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')

django_heroku.settings(locals())

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= os.environ.get('AWS_ID',)
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=os.environ.get('AWS_KEY',)
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME ='clothingandregrandon'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH=False
```

also have s3 buckets set up and that works fine when debug=true. Not sure whats going on. allowed hosts are good and i also did python manage.py collectstatic. anyone know th problem??

26/Feb/2022 03:42:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 as the error
on window it just says Server

Comment: What does the error say? Post your error logs as well.

Comment: @NaeemKhan the error just says "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145

Comment: Is your project deployed on AWS or Heroku? I'm asking this because I see both configurations in your `settings.py`. And what EXACTLY is not running? Your static files? Your project?

Comment: this is just locally that its not working. And the project doesnt work when debug=false. but it works when debug=true @NaeemKhan

Comment: not sure why tho

Comment: You mean on your system where you are developing, the project does not run at all?

Comment: @NaeemKhan its runs but gives me a 500 server error when debug=false. When debug=true it works fine